# How to convert months to days in R?

Tags: r, function, data-science

I have a task: "Let's consider 'today' is 2000-01-01. Convert amount of months applicant living at his/her current address to days".The image shows the columns of my dataframe [image]

I tried to change the entire column in this way, but I got an error

```
d <- as.Date("2000-01-01")
colnames(creditcard)[which(colnames(creditcard) == 'months')] <- 'days'
creditcard<-transform(creditcard, days=as.integer(d - (d - months(days))))
creditcard$days<-sapply(creditcard$days, function(x) as.integer(d - (d - months(x))))
#no applicable method for 'months' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

> dput(head(creditcard))
structure(list(card = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("no", 
"yes"), class = "factor"), reports = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), age = c(37.66667, 33.25, 33.66667, 30.5, 32.16667, 23.25), 
    income = c(4.52, 2.42, 4.5, 2.54, 9.7867, 2.5), share = c(0.03326991, 
    0.005216942, 0.004155556, 0.06521378, 0.06705059, 0.0444384
    ), expenditure = c(124.9833, 9.854167, 15, 137.8692, 546.5033, 
    91.99667), owner = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("no", 
    "yes"), class = "factor"), selfemp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
    dependents = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 0L), days = c(54L, 34L, 
    58L, 25L, 64L, 54L), majorcards = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), active = c(12L, 13L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 1L), income_fam = c(1.13, 
    0.605, 0.9, 2.54, 3.26223333333333, 2.5)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The quick answer is `as.Date("2000-01-01") - dat$months*30`, but it is almost certainly wrong: we don't know how `months` is calculated, it could be 30 or 31 or 30.417 or something else. There is no deterministic "month" that allows reverse-calculating accurate dates. If that's not good enough, then you need to go back to the professor/teacher and ask for clarification.

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(head(creditcard))`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not with the standard functions but package `lubridate` is as standard as a non-base package gets.

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

d <- as.Date("2000-01-01")
start <- d - months(54)
d - start
#> Time difference of 1645 days
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

A one-liner is (note that the **operation is not associative**)

```r
d - (d - months(54))
#> Time difference of 1645 days
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

or

```r
as.integer(d - (d - months(54)))
#> [1] 1645
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

The best way is to rewrite the code as a function and apply the function to the column `days`.

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

month_days <- function(x) {
  d <- Sys.Date()
  as.integer(d - (d - months(x)))
}

month_days(54)
#> [1] 1644

creditcard$days <- month_days(creditcard$days)
creditcard
#>   card reports      age income       share expenditure owner selfemp dependents days majorcards active income_fam
#> 1  yes       0 37.66667 4.5200 0.033269910  124.983300   yes      no          3 1644          1     12   1.130000
#> 2  yes       0 33.25000 2.4200 0.005216942    9.854167    no      no          3 1035          1     13   0.605000
#> 3  yes       0 33.66667 4.5000 0.004155556   15.000000   yes      no          4 1765          1      5   0.900000
#> 4  yes       0 30.50000 2.5400 0.065213780  137.869200    no      no          0  760          1      7   2.540000
#> 5  yes       0 32.16667 9.7867 0.067050590  546.503300   yes      no          2 1948          1      5   3.262233
#> 6  yes       0 23.25000 2.5000 0.044438400   91.996670    no      no          0 1644          1      1   2.500000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I tried to change the whole column in this way, but I get the following error
d <- as.Date("2000-01-01");
colnames(creditcard)[which(colnames(creditcard) == 'months')] <- 'days' ;
creditcard<-transform(creditcard, days=as.integer(d - (d - months(days))));
creditcard$days<-sapply(creditcard$days, function(x) as.integer(d - (d - months(x))));
#no applicable method for 'months' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Comment: @Арина Филатова Please don't post code as comment. See my comment to the question and update the question.

Comment: @Арина Филатова Done, see the edit.